# How to highlight text in an Outlook email using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I used the macro recorder in MS Word 2016 to find and highlight multiple instances of text. I copied that code into MS Outlook 2016 and added some declarations.  It will not use the specified highlight color.

I think it is one of two problems:
(1) I need an Outlook declaration to identify DefaultHightlightColor; or
(2) Instead of using DefaultHighlightColor, I need to specify HighlightColor

```
Sub Pink()
    Dim Ins As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim Document As Word.Document
    Dim Word As Word.Application
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection

    Set Ins = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set Document = Ins.WordEditor
    Set Word = Document.Application
    Set Selection = Word.Selection

    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "Some string"
        .Replacement.Text = "Some string"
        Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdPink
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`wdPink` is part of an enumeration - You can change it to `5` or define your own enumeration for readability:

[Word WdColorIndex Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdcolorindex)

Or

```
Enum wdColorIndex
  wdPink = 5
End Enum
```

and then you can use `wdColorIndex.wdPink`

You are going to have the same problem with `wdFindContinue` by the way...

Comment: Sorry if I'm being thick - but my code works, it just changes the color to yellow (or whatever the last highlight color I used) instead of pink

Comment: OK, try changing it to `vbPink` instead then.

Comment: Nope, same result.

Comment: Then try some of the other color index numbers. If they all produce the same thing, then you have the wrong property.

Comment: It's like it doesn't even recognize the color command - it's only reacting to

Comment: It's like it doesn't even recognize the color command - it's only reacting to the ".Replacement.Highlight = True"

Comment: well the 2 lines after that do not have a `.` in front of them, so they are not being fully qualified like the other lines. (if that helps)

Comment: But this isn't Word. Maybe `Word.Options` etc...? it needs to be fully qualified with SOMETHING.